Unable to get p-value using tbl_summary. Getting FEXACT error 501
I'm new to gtsummary. I have the following code. I'm not able to get the p-value.
Code
 df %>% select(SEX,HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS) %>%
    tbl_summary(by = HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS, # split table by group
      missing = "no" # don't list missing data separately
    ) %>%
     add_p() %>%
   bold_p(t = 0.01)%>%
    bold_labels()

Error
There was an error in 'add_p()/add_difference()' for variable 'SEX', p-value omitted:
Error in stats::fisher.test(structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, : FEXACT error 501.
The hash table key cannot be computed because the largest key
is larger than the largest representable int.
The algorithm cannot proceed.
Reduce the workspace, consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE' or another algorithm.
Image of my table that gets generated without the p-value
I get the same error when I run fisher.test(df$SEX, df$HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS), so it may not have anything to do with gtsummary, but any help appreciated in what may be the issue.
Thank you!

This is an error arising from fisher.test(). As the error message indicates, you can add the fisher.test(simulate.p.value=TRUE) argument to get the function working.
You can pass the argument to the function in add_p() using the test.args argument. Check out the help file for details.

Thank you. That worked!   I have a follow-up question since I'm running into a different error when using the same code in tbl_cross.  t2 = df %>%    tbl_cross(row=EDUC_TR, col = HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS, percent = "cell") %>%    add_p(     test.args = all_tests("fisher.test") ~ list(simulate.p.value = TRUE)     ) %>%  bold_p(t = 0.01)%>%   bold_labels()   Error I get is: Error in map2():
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: EDUC_TR.
Caused by error:
! Error processing test.args argument for element 'EDUC_TR'. Expecting a named vector or list
as the passed value.

The error mentioned in my previous comment goes away when my test.args is simply the list.  df %>%    tbl_cross(row=EDUC_TR, col = HPV_VACCINATION_STATUS, percent = "cell") %>%    add_p(     test.args = list(simulate.p.value = TRUE)     ) %>%  bold_p(t = 0.01)%>%   bold_labels()  I wonder why the test.args code for passing variables to the fisher test worked differently when using tbl_summary vs. tbl_cross. For now, I'm unblocked...
